# Search for different custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I want to filter my posts using search in wordpress.When i use below code

```
function mySearchFilter($query) {
    $post_type = 'blog';
    if ($query->is_search) {
        if (!empty($post_type)) {
           $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
    }
  }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

The results is showing currect.But if I use multiple custom post type how can i get different posts.My url showing post_type=kb_article.Is there any solution for this

Comment: Please edit this question. It's hard to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pre_get_posts` hook.

For example:

```
function search_filter($query) {
   if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
     if ($query->is_search) {
       $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
     }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

[Refer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)